# Why not use XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using AJAX in my web application. However the documentation says to

instead of this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

do this:

```
var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                      .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
```

Why is it better that I do this? What is the difference?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the second approach is not cross-browser...

Comment: Lately the word Ajax is immediately triggering my jQuery reflexes. $.get(url,callbackFunction) is really so much cooler than a bunch of if statements and activeX tests

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guessing that your read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_XMLHttpRequest_from_JavaScript_modules_.2f_XPCOM.c2.a0components) .... That remark is valid for XPCom modules, ie modules that live inside a Mozilla application.  Not for web applications, so you should stick to the standard calls, or use some JS framework to shield you from differences between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with chrome and non-chrome code, the

```
.createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest)
```

works in both cases. You should test if this is still the case.